# Is there a Google REST API to challenge a *different* user to prove they have access to a Google account?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have written a client-side-only peer-to-peer virtual gaming tabletop webapp.  The users sign into it using their Google account (using oAuth via the GAPI javascript library), which is all working fine.

The clients then connect to one another via WebRTC and exchange information, including stating that they are such-and-such a user.  When a remote peer connects, I would like to be able to verify the Google identity that the remote peer claims to be logged in as.

What I'm wondering is if there's an existing mechanism already built into the Google REST APIs which would allow two clients to safely and securely verify each others' claimed identities (presumably through some collaborative challenge-response dance).

I could have clients exchange their `id_token`s (as per the [documentation for signing in to a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)), but that leaks the `id_token` to everyone else.  A hacked client could forward any `id_token`s it receives to other peers, masquerading as a different user (until the expiry time is past.)

Since my webapp has `drive.file` oAuth scope, I could instead implement something myself using Google Drive - each client could generate a keypair, store the public key in a Google Drive file which is world-readable, and then inform any peers that connect of the Drive file ID of the public key.  A client could sanity-check the file ID, and then use the Drive API to get the public key, as well as the Drive file's owner from the file's metadata.  If the remote peer is able to prove it knows the private key corresponding with the world-readable public key, my client can then know that the remote peer is the same user as the owner of the public key Drive file.

However, I would rather use something that already exists, if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use Drive for this, unless your game is only to have fun with your friends. Is this the case? Or is it a published game?

Comment: @Jescanellas it's not a game, it's a gaming tabletop - a 3D space where a Game Master can place maps and miniatures, and players join to see what's happening.  It's free and open source, so not "published" per se, but I do have quite a few users.

The reason it stores its data in Google Drive is to allow the app to work without a dedicated back end, and to give users control of their data.

Comment: @Jescanellas in any case, using Drive to verify identities was listed as an option I'd prefer not to use.